# Solve a constrained optimization problem with a symbolic number of variables using SymPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, mathematical-optimization, symbolic-math

I'm trying to solve a constrained minimization problem using SymPy. For a fixed number of variables, say `w1, w2`, I'm able to do this in the following way:

```
from sympy import *

w1, w2 = var('w1, w2', real = True)
n1, n2 = symbols('n1, n2', integer = True)
p1, p2 = symbols('p1, p2', real = True)
f = w1**2 / (n1 * p1) + w2**2 / (n2 * p2)
g = w1 + w2 - 1

lam = symbols('lambda', real = True)
L = f - lam * g

gradL = [diff(L, c) for c in [w1, w2]]
KKT_eqs = gradL + [g]

stationary_points = solve(KKT_eqs, [w1, w2, lam], dict = True)
```

Are we able to solve this problem for a variable number, say `k`, of variables? I've tried the following:

```
from sympy import *

i = symbols('i', cls = Idx)
k = symbols('k', integer = True)

w = IndexedBase('w', real = True)

n = IndexedBase('n', integer = True)
p = IndexedBase('p', real = True)

f = summation(w[i]**2 / (n[i] * p[i]), (i, 1, k))
g = summation(w[i], (i, 1, k)) - 1

lam = symbols('lambda', real = True)
L = f - lam * g
```

However, I wasn't able to figure out how I need to adopt the remainder of the code.

(I'm new to python so please bear with me.)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is look for a pattern within the concrete cases:

```
>>> from sympy import *
... from sympy.abc import i
... w = IndexedBase('w')
... np = IndexedBase('np')
... lam = symbols('lambda', real = True)
... def go(n):
...  ww = [w[i] for i in range(n)]
...  f = Add(*[wi**2/np[i] for i,wi in enumerate(ww)])
...  g = Add(*ww) - 1
...  L = f - lam * g
...  gradL = [diff(L, c) for c in ww]
...  KKT_eqs = gradL + [g]
...  return solve(KKT_eqs, ww + [lam], dict = True)
>>> go(2)
[{lambda: 2/(np[0] + np[1]), w[0]: np[0]/(np[0] + np[1]), w[1]: np[1]/(np[0] + np[1])}]
>>> go(3)
[{lambda: 2/(np[0] + np[1] + np[2]), w[0]: np[0]/(np[0] + np[1] + np[2]), w[1]: np[1]/(np[0] + np[1] + np[2]), w[2]: np[2]/(np[0] + np[1] + np[2])}]
```

Note: since `n[i]*p[i]` always appear together, those two variables have been combined into one.  Do you see the pattern for the solutions? Try `go(4)` if you don't.

To generalize without concrete insight you might be able to do something with `MatrixExpr`.